# can we add extra table or column in wordpress for adding our data

Tags: database

Just a simple question is it possible
if yes what are the requirements of this
mean i want to make a table for adding songs information in table like

```
link | name | date | size | moviename
```

is it possible
if yes any idea or any suggestion
thanks

Answer (score 4):

You may not need extra custom tables. Create a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) for songs. Then store all the required data (link, name, date, size, etc.) as [post meta data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

The songs would be stored in the `wp_posts` table and the metadata in `wp_postmeta`.

Comment: but one Movie Song page will contain on many songs on one page
so how i'll save the details of all songs in meta deta
like for example
Key = song Name
value = i love u forevevr
an other song name on the same page is
key = song Name
value = let's party tonight

how to call both of these song on the same page
and is it will be ok with thousands of songs

Comment: mean i am going to add songs of thousands films so i have to create round about million meta tags the efficiency of database and word-press will be good or what will happened ?

Comment: and one thing more how i define that this value is of that song on the page of wordpress because i have many songs listed on one movie page
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Codex gives a great introduction in how to create your own database tables [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) :D.